# Show references to a Swift class' property

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

Give a Swift class' property, how can see where it's referenced (get and set) in Xcode? I'm running Xcode 7.1.

Example, select `name` and see where it's referenced.

```
Class Person {
    var name: String?
}
```

I've tried:

- Find Selected Symbol in Workspace - this matches property's type and not the property itself
- Find Call Hierarchy - this just jumps back to the property definition
- Four little squares in upperleft, "Callers" is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, like refactoring, I do not believe this is supported for Swift in Xcode.  I hope this, and refactoring, will be added at some point in the future.  Best bet is to [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com/).